# WPF/Silverlight: Can I easily modify a property that I am binding to?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

For example:

```
 Width={Binding MyWidth}
```

I'd like to do:

```
 Width={Binding MyWidth/2}
```

This doesn't work... I'm wondering if there's an **easy** way to do this. (without writing a converter, and without changing or creating a new property)

Note: not necessarily for Width.. I'm talking about properties in general

Thanks

Comment: depending on other factors, a scaletransform could be an option

Comment: Oh how I wish this was possible!! :D

Answer (score 3):

No you can't.

You have to write a valueconverter. The only thing you can do is use a formatstring to change the format.

But you could write a multipurpose converter that you can give a parameter - it could even be some kind of script you invent so you could use it for all kinds of scenarios, like your division.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had to do this not long ago. Like Rune said, I needed to write a converter. You can use mine if you want.

Example usage:

```
Width="{Binding Width, Converter={StaticResource DoubleOffsetConverter}, ConverterParameter=50%}"
```

And, here's the converter. Your question seems like you only need one-way conversion, although I don't think it'd be too hard to implement ConvertBack to make it two-way if necessary.

```
public class DoubleOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            double valueDouble = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);

            if (parameter != null)
            {
                string paramString = parameter.ToString();
                double paramDouble;
                if (paramString.EndsWith("%"))
                {
                    //
                    // Multiply by the percentage.
                    //
                    if (double.TryParse(paramString.Substring(0, paramString.Length - 1), out paramDouble))
                    {
                        return valueDouble * paramDouble / 100.0;
                    }
                }
                else if (double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out paramDouble))
                {
                    //
                    // Add the offset.
                    //
                    return valueDouble + paramDouble;
                }

            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not in Silverlight, your only options there are as you wrote, either a converter or a new property.

Edit: just checked, doesn't seem to be possible even with WPF, using this article as reference: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDataBinding1.aspx